# Error on Login in paypal parallel payment using MPL Android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using MPL for integrating parallel payment in my application.
But something went wrong. 
When i m trying to login then it gives following exception-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault
            xmlns:axis2ns461789="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <faultcode>axis2ns461789:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The transaction cannot be completed as the sender has some important information missing on file.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns3:FaultMessage
                    xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common"
                    xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
                    <responseEnvelope>
                        <timestamp>2015-11-09T23:50:08.197-08:00</timestamp>
                        <ack>Failure</ack>
                        <correlationId>d69853b9ab551</correlationId>
                        <build>17820627</build>
                    </responseEnvelope>
                    <error>
                        <errorId>520009</errorId>
                        <domain>PLATFORM</domain>
                        <subdomain>Application</subdomain>
                        <severity>Error</severity>
                        <category>Application</category>
                        <message>The transaction cannot be completed as the sender has some important information missing on file.</message>
                    </error>
                </ns3:FaultMessage>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is screen shot where it unable to Login and giving me this error message-

[image]

Note: When i was using MPL pizza app then it worked fine for this paypal id.

Please suggest me, what is going wrong. what important information i have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your account is not locked. Your device has shown that error because your payment total amount is exceeding high-value payment limits which is set by paypal.

If you make high-value payment by web then it should be login properly.
But paypal will need some additional information(like Social Security Number, Passport Number, Alien Registration Number etc) for complete payment.

I suppose, in MPL there is any method which you have to enable then after you device accept high-value payment.

And further details, You can contact to [paypal-techsupport](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Your sandbox account is locked. You'll need to to contact [Merchant Support](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/) to resolve it.